# postion issue in html and css

Tags: html, css

**Expected**

[image: expected ui]

**Position: Fixed**

[[image: when i use postion:fixed]]

**Remove Position: Fixed**

[[image: when i use remove postion:fixed]]

> my html

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container-fluid .wrapper {
  display: flex;
    position: relative;
}

.container-fluid .wrapper .sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #4b4276;
  padding: 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <h2>Paperpay</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-file-invoice"></i>Statements</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-users"></i>Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-newspaper"></i>Newspapers</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main_content">
      <div class="header">Welcome to Paper Pay</div>
      <div class="info">
        welcom to info
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and when to use position 
**new to css help me to reach my goal that's UI new to css help me to reach my goal that's UI **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reference `display: flex` but don't seem to actually use it.

One quick a dirty solution is get rid of `display: flex` if you aren't using it and give main_content a left margin greater or equal to the width of your sidebar.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container-fluid .wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.container-fluid .wrapper .sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #4b4276;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.main_content{
margin-left:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <h2>Paperpay</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-file-invoice"></i>Statements</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-users"></i>Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-newspaper"></i>Newspapers</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main_content">
      <div class="header">Welcome to Paper Pay</div>
      <div class="info">
        welcom to info
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```